# Search one character in a million characters string

Tags: algorithm, search

What's the best approach to search for one character in a million characters string? This is more from an algorithmic point of view rather than how to do it with a particular programming language?

Is binary search a good approach?

Comment: Please share more details. How should binary search help in this case? Is the longer string sorted, such that binary search could be used after all?

Comment: Unless preprocessing is allowed, there is only one way: brute force (try all characters).

Comment: @NicoHaase: if I read correctly, there is just one string.

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes, that's how I understand that too. And that's why I've asked about more details about that string

Comment: @NicoHaase: I was mislead by your "longer string".

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "search". Could mean just check presence, count the number of instances, report the location of the first (or last, or any) occurrence, or return all locations. And again, if preprocessing is allowed, this makes very different solutions.

Comment: I mean check presence. What do you mean by preprocessing?

Comment: Read my answer.

Comment: Is the string sorted, is there a known occurrence % of the character, is any occurrence of the character acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without preprocessing, scan the string until you meet the target character. If you only need to check presence or the location of the first instance, you are done. Otherwise, you need to scan to the end.

With preprocessing

- if you need to report presence or count, form an histogram (count of the instances for every possible value); this can be done in a single pass (with possible early termination if the count is not required). Then a query is done in constant time.
- if you need to report the first instance (or some), fill a table of first-occurrence-indexes for each character value; this can be done in a single pass (with possible early termination). Then a query is done in constant time.
- if you need to report all instances, you can prefill linked lists of all instances of every character; this can be done in a single pass, but the storage cost is heavy (one link per character). Then a query is done in time proportional to the number of occurrences.

Note that sorting with a general sort, then answering the queries by binary search is probably *the worst thing* you can do. General sorting will be more costly than needed (N Log(N) instead of N), and the queries will be expensive (Log(N) instead of 1). Not counting that if you need the location information, you'll have to augment the string with an extra field before sorting.

---

If the characters in the string are known to be in sorted order (a pretty unlikely situation !), the answer is different:

- if you need to query just once, use a dichotomic search (two if you are asked the count or the range where the character is found).
- if you need to perform more queries (at least S Log(S), where S is the size of the alphabet), then you can delimit the ranges of equal characters by a series of dichotomic searches.

Answer (score 0):

Let L be the string length and S the alphabet size.

Without preprocessing, you need a sequential search. It will take a number of comparisons equal to the position of the first occurrence of the target character (or L if absent). Best case 1, worst case L, average case LS/K (for a uniform and balanced distribution with K occurrences of the target character).

With preprocessing, you fill a presence table by a sequential scan of the string. The number of character comparisons will equal the "last" first occurrence of any character (or L if one is absent). Best case S, worst case L. Extra storage of S bits is required. Subsequent queries are done in constant time.